# What is the best way to generate Android Room Migrations?

Tags: android, entity-framework, orm, android-room

Note that I come from a .NET background where I'm familiar with Entity Framework.

So in EF migrations, the actual migrations are generated for you. Basically, you specify in your POCO objects the changes you want. When you add a new migration, it does a diff between the database and the POCO objects and generates a migration script. You barely have to even look at it.

So using Android Room, I'm finding I have to handcraft these migrations myself. And there are rules that mean the system crashes unless the migration you handcraft puts the schema in exactly the state Room thinks it should be based on the POJO objects.

For me, this seems like a tedious and risky task that could be automated (like EF migrations already does). So my question is, is there a tool or something that'll do these migrations automatically? If not, what are some guidelines on how to do these migrations safely or efficently?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if a tool like this exists specifically for Room as of today, but I hardly doubt it, since Room's stable version was released just a few months ago.

One small thing you can get generated is SQL statements for tables creation. 
Just add:

```
javaCompileOptions {
    annotationProcessorOptions {
        arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                             "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
    }
}
```

to android/defaultConfig in your's build.gradle and a [JSON with complete schemas will be generated](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-migration-1a269e1aeef7).

To do these migrations safely you can fully test them - this is well described [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/testing-room-migrations-be93cdb0d975)

Regarding efficiency I would recommend creating direct migrations like `Migration(1, 4)`

Comment: Thanks for this. The table creation statements in the json output are super helpful. Don't forget to ensure `exportSchema = true` in your `@Database` annotations (true by default), or the json file won't be generated.

Answer (score 0):

The android room migrations are problematic, because even a difference of column order will show a failed migration.  But due to sqlite's limitations column type alterations and so forth cannot be done. Do as in Michal's answer and generate the schemas.

[image: schema location]

Then use a [JSON diff tool](http://jsondiff.com/) to see how it generates your particular table.

If the difference is easy, do the necessary alter command in your migration script.  I've pretty much given up on doing this and instead just create a new table the way my new version expects it to be, copy the data from the old table, drop it, and rename the correctly created table.  Here's some code:

```
    static final Migration MIGRATION_3_4 = new Migration(3, 4) {
    @Override
    /**
     * Instead of trying to read the owl droppings of the error message, simply go to the schemas directory
     * and do a table copy of the before and after.  Look for the table creation in the updated schema number
     * then do an insert by doing a select * from the old
     * then remove the old and rename the new
     */
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS crew2 (`crewId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `name` TEXT NOT NULL, `shortName` TEXT, `isCaptain` TEXT)");
        _db.execSQL("INSERT INTO crew2(crewid,name,shortname) SELECT * FROM crew_table");
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE crew_table");
        _db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE crew2 RENAME TO crew_table");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_crew_table_shortName` ON `crew_table` (`shortName`)");

    }
};
```